# How to change display format of time in seconds to Date in X axis in Bokeh Chart

Tags: bokeh

I am plotting two points with current time in seconds on X axis. 
x axis type is set to `datetime`. Time is getting displayed as `540400US` numbers.

I am trying to change format of time to Date format (eg 22-Sep-18 02:22:22). Tried setting formats using `DatetimeTickFormatter` , but it is not changing display format .

```html
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.models.formatters import DatetimeTickFormatter
import pandas as pd
import time as time_
from datetime import datetime

def currentTime():
    return int(round(time_.time()))
data = {'size': [1,2],'time':[currentTime(),currentTime()+1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
p = figure(title = "TEST",x_axis_type='datetime')
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'time'
p.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(seconds=["%M:%S"],minutes=["%M:%S"],minsec=["%M:%S"],hours=["%M:%S"])

#p.scatter(pd.to_datetime(df["time"],unit='s'),df["size"],fill_color="olive",size=10)
p.scatter(df["time"],df["size"],fill_color="olive",size=10)
output_file("test.html", title="test chart")
show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Updates :  Tried changing code to use pd.to_datetime function  .   ie p.scatter(pd.to_datetime(df["time"],unit='s'),df["size"],fill_color="olive",size=10)   this shows data is "ms" format , but still desired format is not coming on X axis

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the time column to a datetime type using the `to_datetime()` function from `pandas`, otherwise it seems bokeh cannot interpret the time correctly.

I think the format on x-axis is coming in ms because you don't have a long enough time frame in the data for the formatting to have any effect, the two values are just one second apart, which is probably consistent in the way datetime axis works in bokeh. For example if you have a long range data (a week for example), and you zoom into the plot, the resolution of the time changes and becomes more precise as you zoom in. If you add more difference between the values, the formatting does work.

Also, if you want the time to appear in the format: `22-Sep-18 02:22:22`, you need to set the tick formatter like this:

```
p.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(days="%d-%b-%Y", hours="%H:%M", seconds="%S" )
```

Full code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.models.formatters import DatetimeTickFormatter
import pandas as pd
import time as time_
from datetime import datetime

def currentTime():
    return int(round(time_.time()))
data = {'size': [1,2],'time':[currentTime(), currentTime() + 24 * 3600]}


df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')
p = figure(title = "TEST",x_axis_type='datetime')
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'time'
p.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(days="%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")
p.scatter(df["time"],df["size"],fill_color="olive",size=10)
output_file("test.html", title="test chart")
show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for response. What i am trying to achieve is to have Date displayed in format eg 24-Sep-2018 08:00:00 for all points on X axis.